# How can I create a simple daemon that spawns other daemons in C?

Tags: c, asynchronous, daemon

I am trying to create a simple daemon that does nothing (just stays alive) and listens for a SIGTERM. Whenever it receives a SIGTERM signal, it should `fork()` itself and create a child that behaves exactly like the parent; then the parent should die and the process should be able to repeat again.

The thing is that once I kill my parent, the child dies upon exiting the signal handler.

```
static void handler(int signum)
{
    if (signum == SIGTERM)
    {
        pid_t pid = fork();
        if (pid < 0)
        {
            perror("Fork failed");
            exit(1);
        }
        if (pid > 0)
        {
            exit(0);
        }
        printf("Child process created!\n");
        // here the child process dies, I expect him to print something and then return to "listening mode"
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    pid_t pid = fork();
    if (pid < 0)
    {
        perror("Fork failed");
        exit(1);
    }
    if (pid > 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    signal(SIGTERM, handler);
    while (1)
    {
        sleep(1);
    }
}
```

If I place the child process on an infinite loop though, it is unable to receive any signal no more, even if I relink it to the handler:

```
static void handler(int signum)
{
    if (signum == SIGTERM)
    {
        pid_t pid = fork();
        if (pid < 0)
        {
            perror("Fork failed");
            exit(1);
        }
        if (pid > 0)
        {
            exit(0);
        }
        // signal(SIGTERM, handler); -> doesn't have any effect neither
        while (1)
        {
            printf("I'm alive\n");//here the child process lives but cannot handle the SIGTERM signal
        }
        
    }
}
```